# Big number modulo a small integer in Openssl

Tags: c, openssl

I was wondering if it is possible that a big number modulo a small integer in Openssl?

Say I generate two big prime numbers:

```
BN_generate_prime(p,512,0,0,0,0,0);
BN_generate_prime(q,512,0,0,0,0,0);
```

and calculate the product `N`:

```
BN_mul(N,p,q,ctx);
```

I would like to test if `N` is a "Blum integer" (N mod 4==3), however I can't figure out how to do this since function `BN_mod` only support big numbers.

Comment: Why not just test if (least-significant) bits 0 and 1 are set? e.g. `(p->d[0] & 0x3 == 0x3)`, or `BN_is_bit_set(p, 0) && BN_is_bit_set(p, 1)` - Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

The best and efficient way is given in jww's answer, which is to call [BN_mod_word()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_add_word.html).

A less efficient way is to do it by converting a small integer a `BIGNUM` first.  It's cumbersome, but not difficult.  I'll show you two ways to create the `BIGNUM`s by computing `11 mod 3` with `BN_mod`.  First, declare a BIGNUM for your numbers.

```
BIGNUM *N = BN_new();
BIGNUM *M = BN_new();
```

**Method 1**:  Convert your number to a string, and then the string to a BIGNUM.

```
#include <sstream>
int n = 11;
std::ostringstream num_str;
num_str << n;
BN_dec2bn( &N, num_str.str().c_str() );
```

(In C you can do `char buf[12]; sprintf(buf, "%d", n); BN_dec2bn(&N, buf);`)

**Method 2**:  Give your number as an array of bytes, but beware that OpenSSL wants your bytes in big endian format, and will always interpret your bytes as a positive number.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>   // For htonl to make the integer big endian
int m = 3;
m = htonl(m);
BN_bin2bn( (unsigned char *) &m, sizeof(m), M);
```

And then just use your OpenSSL function as normal.

```
BN_mod(rem, N, M, ctx);
BN_print_fp(stdout, rem);  // (Using N=11 and M=3 above, this line prints 2)
```

And free your `BIGNUM`s.

```
BN_free(N);
BN_free(M);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if it is possible that a big number modulo a small integer in Openssl?
>
> ... test if N is a "Blum integer" (N mod 4==3), however I can't figure out how to do this since function BN_mod only support big numbers.

Yes, but it needs to be an unsigned integer, which you seem to have with the mod 4 equivalence class. Use `BN_ULONG BN_mod_word(const BIGNUM *a, BN_ULONG w)`.

I use it for validating Diffie-Hellman parameters before using them. See, for example, [Diffie-Hellman Parameter Check (when g = 2, must p mod 24 == 11?)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12961/10496) on the [Crypto Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

The man pages for the function is located at [`BN_mod_word(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_add_word.html).